# Non-Simple Lattice Paths using PathGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics, lattices

I am encoding a lattice walk of steps North, South and East on $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ between the two extremities of the $x$-axis:

```
T1 = Permutations[{N, N, S, S, E, E}, {6}][[4]];
T2 = {1};
For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++,
 If[T1[[i]] == N,
  T2 = Append[T2, T2[[i]] + 1]];
 If[T1[[i]] == E, T2 = Append[T2, T2[[i]] + 3]];
 If[T1[[i]] == S, T2 = Append[T2, T2[[i]] - 1]];]
T2
With[{n = 3}, g = GridGraph[{n, n}];
 HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph@#] & /@ {T2}]
T2 = {1};
```

This code plots the 4th permutation in the list, which is T1={N,N,E,S,S,E}, and finally resets. This looks like:

[image]

However, I cannot plot certain permutations because they are not simple paths. For example {N,N,S,S,E,E} goes over itself: twice N, twice S (then carries on twice E). So it can't be displayed. Try using T1 = {N,N,S,S,E,E}.

Can this be fixed?

(Also, if possible, it would be nice to delete all permutations that go under the $x$-axis at some point, such as {S,S,N,N,E,E}.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T1
```

> {N, N, S, S, E, E}

```
T2
```

> {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 7}

```
With[{n = 3}, g = GridGraph[{n, n}];
  HighlightGraph[ g, 
     {UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1], 
      Style[#, Red]}] & /@ {T2}]
```

[image]

aside, I'd recommend using strings `"N","S","E"` instead of symbols. Especially `N` and `E` since they are reserved system symbols.

Comment: Thank you, this will work great.